# Stop UISwitch from changing states

Tags: swift, xcode, uiswitch

I want to be able to not allow a UISwitch to change if a statement is true.
To set up the cell switch I have

`cell.accessoryView = addAccessory()`

addAccessory is a method that will `addTarget(self, action: selectorMethod, for: .touchUpInside)`, set test and accessibility elements, and return a UISwitch. I have tried

```
if (statement is true) {
addAccessory().isOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "myKey") //the userDefault hasn't changed so I tried keeping it set to this value
}
```

I have also tried the `setOn` method in the `if` block with no luck.

Both the `isOn` and `setOn` attempts do not work. I have it working now but it only works by resetting my accessoryView and just 're-calling' `cell.accessoryView = addAccessory()`. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: `addAccessory().isOn =` is creating a new instance. Your code doesn't make any sense

Comment: That's what I said it did. By 'resetting' I mean it creates a new instance of it with the same values I initially gave it

Comment: I should've written it more clear. I have in instance of it I just wrote it down like that to try to be less confusing, but that backfired

Comment: Do you know how to programmatically not let the cell change when selected?

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer: `toggle.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Note that this different from what you asked me. If you don't want to allow the user to select the cell you can deselect it inside collection view didSelectItemAt method